# Error installing Cassandra: NoClassDefFoundError RMIExporter

Tags: java, ubuntu, cassandra, virtualbox

I am trying to install Apache Cassandra 3.11 in a single node virtualbox VM with Ubuntu 14.04, and am following the instalation guide provided here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04 .

I installed java 8

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Then did the following steps to install Cassandra:

```
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" |sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
echo "deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list

gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys F758CE318D77295D
gpg --export --armor F758CE318D77295D | sudo apt-key add -

gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 2B5C1B00
gpg --export --armor 2B5C1B00 | sudo apt-key add -

gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0353B12C
gpg --export --armor 0353B12C | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cassandra
```

Then I ran

```
sudo service cassandra status
* could not access pidfile for Cassandra
```

So I changed

```
CMD_PATT="cassandra.+CassandraDaemon" to "cassandra"
```

in

```
sudo nano +60 /etc/init.d/cassandra
```

However when I ran cassandra service again, it returned the same result.
I tried to execute cassandra directly, like this:

sudo -su  cassandra

And I got the error:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:/home$
WARN  [main] 2017-06-30 17:52:27,800 DatabaseDescriptor.java:540 - Only 
24.622GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to 
your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2017-06-30 17:52:27,928 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - 
Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, 
window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2017-06-30 17:52:27,929 DatabaseDescriptor.java:710 - Back-
pressure is disabled with strategy 
org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, 
flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2017-06-30 17:52:28,430 FileUtils.java:78 - Cannot initialize 
un-mmaper.  (Are you using a non-Oracle JVM?)  Compacted data files will not 
be removed promptly.  Consider using an Oracle JVM or using standard disk 
access mode
Exception (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) encountered during startup: 
com/sun/jmx/remote/internal/RMIExporter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jmx/remote/internal/RMIExporter
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
at 

  java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:91)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.RMIExporter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
... 14 more
ERROR [main] 2017-06-30 17:52:28,536 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception 
encountered during startup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jmx/remote/internal/RMIExporter
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007) ~
[na:na]
atjava.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.ja
va:174) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassL
oader.java:801) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNul
l(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinCl
assLoader.java:622) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoa
der.java:580) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassL
oaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
atorg.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.j
ava:91) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
atorg.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.
java:143) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
atorg.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:18
8) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
atorg.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java
:600) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
atorg.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689
) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.RMIExporter
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoa
der.java:582) ~[na:na]
atjava.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassL
oaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
... 14 common frames omitted
```

What did I miss? Is this an error with the java instalation? Should I lower the Cassandra version? Is it something with the VM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on Windows. At the time, my JAVA_HOME was set to JDK 1.9. I changed it to point to JRE1.8.0_144 and it worked. Also made sure I had Python 2.7 installed (not sure if that matters for you).